# How to make Pseudo classes with commas work?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

So the problem is when i try to give pseudo classes same css properties and do it with comma it just doesn't work. But separatly they work great.

```
ul > li:not(:first-child), ul > li:not(:last-child){
color: aqua;}
```

Maybe i am putting comma somewhere not right?

Comment: it's a logic problem. If I am not a first-child then I am a last-child and if I am not a last-child I am a first-child. So you will always select all the elements

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list of selectors to the `:not()` pseudoclass:

```css
ul > li:not(:first-child, :last-child) {
  color: aqua;
}
```